# Google App Engine Keys Only Query with CURSOR

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I'm Fetching Datastore Entities using PersistenceManager Query which has more than 10000 entities, I would like to fetch only the keys of the Entity, for that I'm using cursor of limit 1000, But the cursor is null after fetching

```
PersistenceManager       pm     =   PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
      Query                       q     = null;
      List<String>           idList     = null;
      int               cursorLimit     =   1000;
      Map<String, Object> cursorMap     =   null;
      Cursor              cursorObj     =   null;
      CommonUtil            utility     =   new CommonUtil();
      HashMap<String, Object> responseMap = null;



        responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Query   q   = pm.newQuery("select id from " + Person.class.getName());

        if( requestMap.containsKey("cursor") )
        {
            cursorMap     = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            cursorObj     = Cursor.fromWebSafeString( String.valueOf( requestMap.get("cursor") )  );
            cursorMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursorObj);
            q.setExtensions(cursorMap);
        }
        q.setRange(0, cursorLimit);
        idList = (List<String>) q.execute();
        cursorObj       = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(idList);

        responseMap.put("contactIdList", idList);

        if(idList.size() == cursorLimit && cursorObj != null)
            responseMap.put("cursor", cursorObj.toWebSafeString());
        else
            responseMap.put("cursor", "");

        q.closeAll();
        pm.close();
```

But the cursorObj is always null, Has anyone come up with this issue or how to overcome it

The Cursor is working perfectly while fetching whole entity, But in keys only query alone its not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try the [keys-only query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries):

```java
Query<Key> query = Query.newKeyQueryBuilder().setKind("Task").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved the above cursor issue with the below code on the same day, Thank you

```
final DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
          FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(cursorLimit);

          if( requestMap.containsKey("cursor"))
          {
              fetchOptions.startCursor(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(requestMap.get("cursor") ));
          }

            q = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("Contact").setKeysOnly();              
            PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);                                
            results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);               
            cursorObj = results.getCursor();
```

This LowLevel API Resolves the problem